# Pass user_id in a table to another page

Tags: php, html

I have a list of users that I'm reporting in a table. The first column contains the user_id, and I want to pass that to another page that displays the users details.  I don't want to pass it through the URL with $_GET.  How do I do this?  I can use only HTML & PHP.  One post I saw seemed like it was on the right track, but I can't get it to work.  Here's what I have:

```
<h1>Maintain Users</h1>
<div id="ir-report">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class = "table tr">
            <th class="table th">User Id</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Activated?</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Account Nbr</th>
        </tr>
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {?>
        <tr class="table tr">
            <td class ="table td" onclick="submit_id($row['user_id'])"><img src="images\editpensil.jpg" alt="UserId" width="25" height="25"></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['first_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['active'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['acct_nbr'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </table>
</div>
```

What I was expecting to happen is that "on click" the function submit_id($var) would be called.  To test that this is working, my function is very simple for the moment:

```
function submit_id($var) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

But nothing happens when I clime on the edit icon (editpensil.jpg).  The application doesn't appear to try and execute anything.  What am I missing?  -- Thanks.

Comment: `onclick="submit_id()"` calls a JavaScript function not a PHP function.

Comment: View your HTML source for `<td class ="table td" onclick="submit_id($row['user_id'])">` and it will reveal how it's being passed through; being `""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a PHP function from an `onclick` attribute, or any other `on` attribute.  Those functions must be Javascript functions.

If you really need/want to not pass the id through GET, you can wrap the table in a `<form>` with the `action` set to the page you want to send it to, with a `method` of `POST` and a hidden input field.  I know your question says you can only use HTML and PHP; without Javascript, the only way you can really do this is to add a button to the form/table.  You could use CSS to style it so it looks like a link, or anything not-button like.

Example without Javascript:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <tr class="table tr">
    <td class ="table td">
      <img src="images\editpensil.jpg" alt="UserId" width="25" height="25">
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['first_name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['active'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['acct_nbr'] ?></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Link to" /></td>
  </tr>
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>" />
</form>
```

When that button is clicked, the form will be posted to `index.php` and you can get to the id through `$_POST['user_id']`

---

If you are willing and able to use Javascript, you should be able to do the following HTML/PHP:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="user_form_<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>">
  <tr class="table tr">
    <td class ="table td user_id_link" data-userid="<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>">
      <img src="images\editpensil.jpg" alt="UserId" width="25" height="25">
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['first_name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['active'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['acct_nbr'] ?></td>
  </tr>
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>" />
</form>
```

And the following Javascript, although this will only work in IE9+:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('user_id_link');

for (link in links) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var formId = 'user_form_' + this.userid;
    document.getElementById(formId).submit();
  }, false);
}
```

---

Or the much cleaner jQuery version, which has better browser compatibility and is really an invaluable toolkit for a web developer:

HTML/PHP:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <tr class="table tr">
    <td class ="table td user-id-link">
      <img src="images\editpensil.jpg" alt="UserId" width="25" height="25">
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['first_name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['active'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['acct_nbr'] ?></td>
  </tr>
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>" />
</form>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('.user-id-link').on('click', function() {
     $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your very thorough response, I'll give these a try in the morning.  Wrapping the table row in a form makes sense.  At this moment I don't understand exactly what you shared, but I'll look forward to learning more tinkering with it.  Can you tell me what the significance of "/>" is?  I don't know what the forward slash is for.  --Thanks.

Comment: That's a shorthand for closing an HTML tag without a separate closing tag.  In HTML, `input` tags (among others like `img`) aren't supposed to have closing tags.  XHTML, which is basically a stricter and more compliant HTML, requires you to have the `/>` on the tag.  You don't **have** to have it, but its considered a good practice.

Comment: This was the answer. onijim got me 98% of the way there.  I bit the bullet and got more familiar with jQuery, which was the last (and recommended) solution.  Ultimately there was two changes I had to make to to make it work.  I commented out the original suggestion, and added what I had to change.  Works like a charm.  Thanks onijim!

Comment: Glad to help.  Looks like the edit was rejected by reviewers.  The purpose of using a class instead of id for `user-id-link` is because ids are supposed to be unique.  It looks like you have multiple of these tables on the page, so by assigning a class and registering the click event, each table will submit the form its a part of.

Comment: Oh well...  "The Man" can reject the edits if he wants.  There were 3 of them.  Simple fact is that the code just doesn't work without two of the three.  My code is working perfectly now with all three.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're mixing PHP and JS. The function called in an `onclick` handler must be JS, it cannot be php.
2. What's wrong with passing the id through the URL? That's quite obviously the only simple practical solution. Alternatives are:

   - using cookies, but that's a mess if a user opens multiple tabs/windows on your site, or wants to bookmark the page, or for a reopen after restart of the browser. And that really doesn't help much.
   - using some kind of other id that points to the user id, but that's just adding another layer for not much.

Unless you tell us exactly why you don't want to pass the id through the URL, it will be difficult to suggest anything.

Comment: I don't want to pass the user id through the URL, because I don't want others to be able to edit the URL and gain access to someone else's profile.  I have a dynamic encryption method worked up that would make it difficult for someone to do so, but nothing is impossible.  I agree that passing it through the URL is straight forward, I just thought that surely others have had my same security concern, and since this operation has to be fairly common, there must be a straight forward alternate approach using $_POST or something that I'm just missing.  Hope that explains it.  Thanks.

Comment: Changing it to a POST makes it just marginally more difficult. If what you want to do is allow a user to edit his own profile, then you must most definitely use some form of authentication (usually involving cookies), and that should let you know the user's id without having to pass it via the URL or any other way.

Comment: The table contains lists many users, the purpose of which is for an administrator to select one and be redirected to a page specific to that user where modifications can be made to that user's profile.  For example, a change in access/security level.  The user can't be permitted to make his/her own selection of access level -- it would defeat the purpose.